How to deal with multiple bitmaps loading and rendering on a canvas (having quality and performance in mind)?
I'm building an app where the user will be able to add multiple images to be drawn on the Canvas.
Those images may have different sizes and the user will be able to zoom in/out the canvas.
What's the best advice about loading those images bitmaps (which may be many at a time) and maintaining a good render quality and performance (60+ fps)?

Fps? What are you doing?
